# Determinants of the sum of two matrices and their eigenvalues

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

I know some basic property of determinant. I read an article and see this formula:
\begin{equation}
|(\delta-p-1)D+S|=\bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}(D)\bigg) \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{p}(\delta-p-1)\lambda_{i}(D^{-1}S)\bigg)
\end{equation}
$D$ and $S$ is $p\times p$ and a symmetric matrix, $\lambda_{i}(M)$ represents $i$th largest eigenvalues of $M$, and $\delta>p+1$. When I implement above formula in R the above formula is not established.

Can anyone give hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like $D$ can be assumed to be invertible so we have
$$
(\delta - p -1) D + S = D\left((\delta - p - 1) I + D^{-1}S\right)
$$
and by the fact that $|AB|=|A||B|$ we have
$$
|(\delta - p -1) D + S| = |D||(\delta - p - 1) I + D^{-1}S| \\
= \left(\prod_{i=1}^p \lambda_i(D)\right)\left(\prod_{i=1}^p (\delta - p - 1) + \lambda_i(D^{-1}S)\right)
$$
so maybe there is a typo in the formula and it should have $\delta - p - 1$ being added instead of multiplied?

Comment: Thanks jld. you are right,

Comment: @Omid great, glad this helped!